# How to add Xamarin.Auth for Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.auth

I need `Xamarin.Auth` for my `WindowsPhone` project in `Xamarin`. There is an experimental branch on `GitHub`: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth.git

How do i add this as a reference to my project? I can't find any `DLL`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this page within the `GitHub` project [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/tree/master/src) it does not look like this particular GitHub project has a `WindowsPhone` version as part of it.

On the official `Xamarin.Auth` component `v1.2.3.1` [here](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.auth) it looks like this is only available for `iOS` and `Android` at present.

The 'experimental' branch I think you require is [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/tree/experimental-winphone), which the `src` folder has a `WindowsPhone` version included.

If you download that, and include the `Xamarin.Auth.WindowsPhone.csproj` you will be able to compile it and consume once referenced.

**Update 1:-**

For the 'experimental' branch, downloading the source isn't enough to load the `WindowsPhone` project as it will complain about an `Import` statement being incorrect.

You need to manually edit the `Xamarin.Auth.WindowsPhone.csproj` and remove the line:-

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.7\tools\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets" />
```

Also, the solution `Xamarin.Auth.sln`, doesn't include the `WindowsPhone` project by default.

Once you've done the previous change of removing the `Import`, you will be able to add the `WindowsPhone` project to the solution and it will load up without complaining.

When you do a compilation on the `Xamarin.Auth.WindowsPhone` project it will retrieve the latest `Microsoft.BCL` reference and restore it form `NuGet` and compile the project successfully for WindowsPhone.

You will then have your `DLL`s in the `Bin` folder that you can reference from your other project.

Comment: How do I compile the csproj and add as a reference for my project?

Comment: Add the .csproj to your solution and compile it.  Should it require any of the other projects you will need to add that in order to get it to successfully compile.  Once you have done that, just add a project reference from your project to it and you will be able to use it.

Comment: When i try to add the .csproj to my solution i get this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pd1vkxxzaf46jjx/screenshot.png?dl=0

Comment: They file isn't on github so it means i'm lost?

Comment: Load the solution file from https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/tree/experimental-winphone/src .  You will see a file called Xamarin.Auth.sln.  That should have all these references for external libraries already reference and set up.

Comment: When i load that i don't see the windows phone project ... So can't compile there

Comment: @MathisseDeStrooper There was issues in the project.  I've posted an update (see Update 1) that describes what you need to do, to load it, and compile the WindowsPhone project successfully.